# Using Array.prototype.find() to check existence and return a boolean

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check for the existence of a `site` in my `siteList`. I'm getting this data from the command line and I'm trying to make sure the user inputs a site that is in the list, if they don't, they get a `usagePrompt()`

This is the site list

```
var siteList = [
    { site: 'github', password: null },
    { site: 'stackoverflow', password: null }
]
```

This is the if statement it's going in

```
if (!process.argv[2] || !process.argv[3] || /* PROBLEM */)) {
    usagePrompt()
}
```

And this is my `/* PROBLEM */` check that I'm going to replace the comment with.

```
console.log(typeof(siteList.find(site => site.site == process.argv[2]) != 'undefined'))
```

I want to `.find()` the site, and if it exists it should therefore not be undefined - but this just returns `boolean`, which exists and is `true` in the if statement regardless of whether the site is in the list.

Comment: You were looking for `some`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some , not find.

Comment: @TravisJ daaaamn that's awesome

Comment: Note that in your code you have a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: @trincot fixed it